# C preprocessor macro for pointer to structure member

Tags: c, pointers, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to make a **C** macro to replace an if statement.

I've never been able to get a good grasp of **C** macros, do I need to do token
pasting?

```
#define BROWSER_HTML_HOW_OPENTAG 0x19939292
structure  { dword how;  } _tag;
structure  { _tag cur_tag;  } _ibot;

// works fine
foo()
{
    _ibot*ibot;
    if(ibot->cur_tag->how==BROWSER_HTML_HOW_OPENTAG) { } // do something
}
```

but I want to implement this

```
#define browserTagCheck(tag,how)    (tag->how==how)
foo()
{
    _ibot*ibot;
    if(browserTagCheck(ibot->cur_tag,BROWSER_HTML_HOW_OPENTAG) {} // do something
}
```

I get an error:

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant|

Comment: You've left off a `)` in your `if()`. Also, it's `struct` not `structure`.

Comment: It's not the main problem, but there is a missing parenthesis in your `if`.

Comment: We have to assume this is pseudo code, since it isn't valid C code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the name `how` in two senses: as a member of `cur_tag`, and as an argument to your `browserTagCheck` macro.  Try using a different name for the macro argument.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.. Is there a way to make the macro legal using the same name.. ? using some kind of parenthesis around it ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but even if there were, that doesn't sound to me like it would be great for clarity...  How about using a similar name, such as `_how`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Never try to re-invent the C language, it is very poor practice.

Instead, I would strongly suggest this:

```
inline bool browserTagCheck (const struct something_t* x)
{
  return x->tag == BROWSER_HTML_HOW_OPENTAG;
}


...

if(browserTagCheck(&ibot))
{
  doStuff();
}
```

Inlining is most likely not even needed, since this appears to be some sort of web/html app with no real time requirements.